# Select objects with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am looking at three different models/entities. One is called `Model:Idea`, one is called `Model:IdeaDetail` and the other is called `Model:IdeaDetailValue`.

IdeaDetail has a few different columns, including `Idea` (which is idea_id in the database, but $idea object in my model class) and `IdeaDetailValue` (idea_detail_value_id in the database, but $ideaDetailValue as an object in the model).

So basically, what I'm trying to do is select out a list of `Idea` objects by querying `IdeaDetail`.

```
$queryBuilder
->select('id.idea')
->from('Model:IdeaDetail', 'id')
->where('IDENTITY(id.ideaDetailValue) IN (:ideaDetailValueIds)')
->setParameter('ideaDetailValueIds', $ideaDetailValueIds)
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

This fails though, with this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 10 near 'task FROM Model:IdeaDetail': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong to select `id.idea` (according to the error, in fact, you probably select `id.task`), and also you cannot use `IDENTITY()` in this case.

You should join your tables to achieve the desired effect. Something like this should work:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('idea')
    ->from('Model:IdeaDetail', 'id')
    ->leftJoin('Model:IdeaDetailValue', 'idea')
    ->where('idea.id IN (:ideaDetailValueIds)')
    ->setParameter('ideaDetailValueIds', $ideaDetailValueIds)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```